# Where to do Content View Bussiness Logic Operations

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, maui, custom-controls

I'm working on a .net maui app and i need to get and set data in my custom control.

The goal is:

[Operation Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDo8c.png)

The page:

```
    <ContentPage
    x:Class="V7.UIS.MauiMobile.Views.AboutPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:V7.UIS.MauiMobile.Controls.Views"    
    xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:V7.UIS.MauiMobile.ViewModels"
    Title="About"
    ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true"
    x:DataType="viewmodel:AboutViewModel"
    BackgroundColor="{StaticResource NormalBackgroundColor}">

    <VerticalStackLayout>

        <controls:ItemBarcodeSearchView />

        <Entry Text="Count" />
        <Button
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Command="{Binding AddCommand}"
            Text="Add" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Custom control xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView
    x:Class="V7.UIS.MauiMobile.Controls.Views.ItemBarcodeSearchView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:dxe="clr-namespace:DevExpress.Maui.Editors;assembly=DevExpress.Maui.Editors"
    x:Name="BarcodeSearchView">
    <ContentView.ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <VerticalStackLayout>
                <Grid
                    x:Name="ButtonGrid"
                    Margin="5"
                    IsVisible="{TemplateBinding IsVisibleButtonGrid}">
                    <Button Clicked="ShowView" Text="Enter Barcode" />
                </Grid>
                <Grid
                    x:Name="DetailGrid"
                    Padding="15"
                    ColumnDefinitions="*"
                    ColumnSpacing="20"
                    IsVisible="{TemplateBinding IsVisibleDetailGrid}"
                    RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto"
                    VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <dxe:TextEdit
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Margin="0"
                        ClearIconCommand="{TemplateBinding ClearFieldsCommand}"
                        ClearIconVisibility="Always"
                        LabelText="Barcode"
                        Text="{TemplateBinding Barcode}" />
                    <dxe:TextEdit
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Margin="0"
                        ClearIconVisibility="Never"
                        LabelText="Item"
                        Text="{TemplateBinding ItemDescription}" />                    
                    <Button
                        Grid.Row="6"
                        Margin="0,10,0,0"
                        Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference BarcodeSearchView}, Path=Search}"
                        Text="Search" />
                    <Button
                        Grid.Row="7"
                        Margin="0,10,0,0"
                        Clicked="SendBarcodeDetails"
                        Text="Ok" />
                </Grid>
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentView.ControlTemplate>
</ContentView>
```

When i press search button i want to execute this command for set itemdescription. This is the bussiness logic of that content view and i dont want to repeat this code over and over again.:

```
private readonly HttpClient _client;

public blabla(IHttpClientFactory factory)
{
_client = factory?.CreateClient(AppConstants.ApiName);
}

GetBarcodeDetailQuery query = new()
{
    Barcode = barcode
};
await client.GetDataFromApi<GetBarcodeDetailQuery, GetBarcodeDetailViewModel>("Cards/ItemBarcode/GetBarcodeDetail", query, FindBarcodeCallBack);
```

Where should i place this operation and how? i cant figure it out for a week.

Custom control xaml.cs :

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using V7.UIS.MauiMobile.Models;

namespace V7.UIS.MauiMobile.Controls.Views;

public partial class ItemBarcodeSearchView : ContentView
{
    public ItemBarcodeSearchView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        IsVisibleButtonGrid = "true";
        IsVisibleDetailGrid = "false";
    }

    public event EventHandler<ItemBarcodeDetail> BarcodeDetailsReady;

    public static readonly BindableProperty BarcodeProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Barcode), typeof(string), typeof(ItemBarcodeSearchView));
    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemDescriptionProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemDescription), typeof(string), typeof(ItemBarcodeSearchView));    
    public static readonly BindableProperty IsVisibleButtonGridProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsVisibleButtonGrid), typeof(string), typeof(ItemBarcodeSearchView));
    public static readonly BindableProperty IsVisibleDetailGridProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsVisibleDetailGrid), typeof(string), typeof(ItemBarcodeSearchView));
    public static readonly BindableProperty SearchProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Search), typeof(RelayCommand), typeof(ItemBarcodeSearchView));

    public RelayCommand Search
    {
        get => (RelayCommand)GetValue(SearchProperty);
        set => SetValue(SearchProperty, value);
    }
    public string IsVisibleButtonGrid
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(IsVisibleButtonGridProperty);
        set => SetValue(IsVisibleButtonGridProperty, value);
    }
    public string IsVisibleDetailGrid
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(IsVisibleDetailGridProperty);
        set => SetValue(IsVisibleDetailGridProperty, value);
    }
    public string Barcode
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(BarcodeProperty);
        set => SetValue(BarcodeProperty, value);
    }
    public string ItemDescription
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(ItemDescriptionProperty);
        set => SetValue(ItemDescriptionProperty, value);
    }
    
    [RelayCommand]
    public void ClearFields()
    {
        Barcode = string.Empty;
        ItemDescription = string.Empty;        
    }

    private void SendBarcodeDetails(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ItemBarcodeDetail itemBarcodeDetail = new()
        {
            Barcode = Barcode,
            ItemDescription = ItemDescription            
        };
        BarcodeDetailsReady?.Invoke(sender, itemBarcodeDetail);
        IsVisibleButtonGrid = "true";
        IsVisibleDetailGrid = "false";
    }
    private void ShowView(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IsVisibleButtonGrid = "false";
        IsVisibleDetailGrid = "true";
    }
}
```

Hope someone here can help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling a parameterized constructor from XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083159/calling-a-parameterized-constructor-from-xaml)

Comment: @H.A.H. thank you for your answer but also i asked this: should contentview has bussiness logic in it or should i have to bind it to viewmodel or something else i cant find the answer

Comment: @Okanalagas All business logic belongs to a ViewModel. That ViewModel can hold reference to other classes, that contain reusable code, sometimes named "Services". Avoid putting business logic in your ContentView (Page, Custom control or something else) at all cost. I am using CommunityToolkit.MVVM. Highly recommending it for MAUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ContentView` class defines a Content property, of type View, which represents the content of the `ContentView`. This property is backed by a `BindableProperty` object, which means that it can be the target of data bindings, and styled.

The ContentView class offers little functionality by itself but can be used to create a custom control. The process for creating a custom control is to:

- Create a class that derives from the ContentView class.
- Define any control properties or events in the code-behind file for
  the custom control.
- Define the UI for the custom control.

For more information, you can check official document: [Create a custom control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/contentview#create-a-custom-control).

**Note:**

You can also check the sample here [ContentView Demos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-contentviewdemos/) which will help you understand how to create a custom control with `ContentView`. Although this sample is an app for Xamarin form, it also applies to MAUI.

Comment: Can i use services like httpclientfactory in custom controls ? Is it best practice to do it for repetitive operations

Comment: `ContentView` is a control used to present various UIs and is reusable. For code such as service like `httpclient`, we generally do not recommend adding it to the `ContentView`. We often use MVVM implementations, often putting code such as service requests in the ViewModel. For more information about MVVM, you can check document [The Model-View-ViewModel Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/mvvm).

Comment: Hi  @Okanalagas, we usually set the `BindContext`t for our pages not the customview(e.g. `ItemBarcodeSearchView `).  You can add the `HttpClient ` to the Page's ViewModel and request data in the Page's ViewModel.  And there are some similar threads about this, you can check them here: [thread 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75637540/binding-to-entry-element-does-not-update-entry-text-more-than-once-maui/75641341#75641341) and  [thread 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76696174/binding-button-command-in-contentview-to-parents-viewmodel-in-net-maui-app/76709973#76709973).

Comment: Thanks for answer but still i want to ask this. I want to use this component in multiple places. Wouldn't such an approach lead to code repetition?

Comment: Yes, a custom control itself can be reused. We just need to pass necessary parameters to it.

Comment: If you try to create a demo according to the link I shared, you'll learn more about custom controls and discover that this is indeed the case.

Comment: @Jessie-Zhang-MSFT  my experience is not enough to figure out this easliy let me make more cleare the problem with a photo here is link https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDo8c.png

Comment: Could you please post the latest code of `ItemBarcodeControl.xaml ` and `ItemBarcodeControl.xaml.cs ` ?

Comment: @jessie-zhang-msft okay i reshaped the question for this purpose thank you for your helps

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this it works but is it best practice to use im not sure.

Here is the page:

```
<ContentPage    
    xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:V7.UIS.MauiMobile.ViewModels"
    x:DataType="viewmodel:AboutViewModel"
    Title="About">
    <VerticalStackLayout>

        <controls:ItemBarcodeSearchView HttpClient="{Binding HttpClient}" />

        <Entry Text="Count" />
        <Button
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Text="Add"/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

```
using V7.UIS.MauiMobile.Constants;

namespace V7.UIS.MauiMobile.ViewModels
{
    public class AboutViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _client;

        public const string ViewName = "AboutPage";

        public AboutViewModel(IHttpClientFactory factory)
        {
            Title = "About";
            _client = factory?.CreateClient(AppConstants.ApiName);
        }
        public HttpClient HttpClient => _client;
    }
}
```

Here is custom control :

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using V7.BaseApplication.AppModels.Erp.Cards.Item.ItemBarcode.Queries;
using V7.BaseApplication.AppModels.Erp.Cards.Item.ItemBarcode.ViewModel;
using V7.UIS.MauiMobile.Helpers;
using V7.UIS.MauiMobile.Models;

namespace V7.UIS.MauiMobile.Controls.Views;

public partial class ItemBarcodeSearchView : ContentView
{
    public ItemBarcodeSearchView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        IsVisibleButtonGrid = "true";
        IsVisibleDetailGrid = "false";
    }

    public event EventHandler<ItemBarcodeDetail> BarcodeDetailsReady;

    #region PropertyDefinition 

    public static readonly BindableProperty BarcodeProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Barcode), typeof(string), typeof(ItemBarcodeSearchView));
    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemDescriptionProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemDescription), typeof(string), typeof(ItemBarcodeSearchView));
    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemUnitProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemUnit), typeof(string), typeof(ItemBarcodeSearchView));
    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemLotProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemLot), typeof(string), typeof(ItemBarcodeSearchView));
    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemSerialNumberProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemSerialNumber), typeof(string), typeof(ItemBarcodeSearchView));
    public static readonly BindableProperty QuantityProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Quantity), typeof(string), typeof(ItemBarcodeSearchView));
    public static readonly BindableProperty IsVisibleButtonGridProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsVisibleButtonGrid), typeof(string), typeof(ItemBarcodeSearchView));
    public static readonly BindableProperty IsVisibleDetailGridProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsVisibleDetailGrid), typeof(string), typeof(ItemBarcodeSearchView));
    public static readonly BindableProperty HttpClientProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(HttpClient), typeof(HttpClient), typeof(ItemBarcodeSearchView));
    public HttpClient HttpClient
    {
        get => (HttpClient)GetValue(HttpClientProperty);
        set => SetValue(HttpClientProperty, value);
    }
    public string IsVisibleButtonGrid
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(IsVisibleButtonGridProperty);
        set => SetValue(IsVisibleButtonGridProperty, value);
    }
    public string IsVisibleDetailGrid
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(IsVisibleDetailGridProperty);
        set => SetValue(IsVisibleDetailGridProperty, value);
    }
    public string Barcode
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(BarcodeProperty);
        set => SetValue(BarcodeProperty, value);
    }
    public string ItemDescription
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(ItemDescriptionProperty);
        set => SetValue(ItemDescriptionProperty, value);
    }
    public string ItemUnit
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(ItemUnitProperty);
        set => SetValue(ItemUnitProperty, value);
    }
    public string ItemLot
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(ItemLotProperty);
        set => SetValue(ItemLotProperty, value);
    }
    public string ItemSerialNumber
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(ItemSerialNumberProperty);
        set => SetValue(ItemSerialNumberProperty, value);
    }
    public string Quantity
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(QuantityProperty);
        set => SetValue(QuantityProperty, value);
    }
    #endregion

    private void ShowView(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IsVisibleButtonGrid = "false";
        IsVisibleDetailGrid = "true";
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    public void ClearFields()
    {
        Barcode = string.Empty;
        ItemDescription = string.Empty;
        ItemUnit = string.Empty;
        ItemLot = string.Empty;
        ItemSerialNumber = string.Empty;
        Quantity = string.Empty;
    }
    [RelayCommand]
    public async Task Search()
    {
        await FindItemDetails(Barcode, HttpClient);
    }

    public async Task FindItemDetails(string barcode, HttpClient client)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(barcode))
        {
            GetBarcodeDetailQuery query = new()
            {
                Barcode = barcode
            };
            await client.GetDataFromApi<GetBarcodeDetailQuery, GetBarcodeDetailViewModel>("Cards/ItemBarcode/GetBarcodeDetail", query, FindBarcodeCallBack);
        }
        else
        {
            await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Hata", "Lütfen bir barkod giriniz.", "Ok");
        }
    }

    void FindBarcodeCallBack(GetBarcodeDetailViewModel vm)
    {
        ItemDescription = vm.Item.Description;
        ItemUnit = vm.ItemUnits.FirstOrDefault().ToString();
        ItemLot = vm.Lot.ToString();
        ItemSerialNumber = vm.SerialNumber.ToString();
        Quantity = "0";
    }

    private void SendBarcodeDetails(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ItemBarcodeDetail itemBarcodeDetail = new()
        {
            Barcode = Barcode,
            ItemDescription = ItemDescription,
            ItemUnit = ItemUnit,
            ItemLot = ItemLot,
            ItemSerialNumber = ItemSerialNumber,
            Quantity = Quantity,
        };
        BarcodeDetailsReady?.Invoke(sender, itemBarcodeDetail);
        IsVisibleButtonGrid = "true";
        IsVisibleDetailGrid = "false";
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to provide an explanation for the content you've shared in your response.